# Coq : How to correctly remember dependent values without messing up the induction hypothesis?

Tags: coq, proof, dependent-type

I have an induction scheme for a vector holding a leb value (`x <= y`),

```
Definition vector_ind_with_leb : forall (A : Type) (P : forall n y: nat, y <= n -> vector A n -> Prop),
       (forall (n : nat) (y : nat) (H : S y <= S n) (a : A) (v : vector A n),
        P n y (le_S_n _ _ H) v -> P (S n) (S y) H (insert a v)) ->
       (forall (n : nat) (H : 0 <= S n) (a : A) (v : vector A n),
         P (S n) 0 H (insert a v)) ->     
        (forall (y : nat) (H : 0 <= 0), P 0 0 H (empty A)) -> forall (n : nat) (y : nat) (Heq : y <= n) (v : vector A n), P n y Heq v.

have : forall n, 0 <= S n -> 0 <= n.
auto with arith.

move => P' A P H K K'.
refine ( fix Ffix (x : nat) (y : nat) (Heq : y <= x) (x0 : vector _ x) {struct x0} : 
       P x y Heq x0 := _).

destruct x0.
destruct y.
refine (K n Heq a _).
refine (H n _ Heq a _ (Ffix _ y _ x0)).
  have : forall y, y <= 0 -> y = 0.
    auto with arith.

move => F'.
set only_0 := F' _ Heq.
destruct y.
refine (K' 0 Heq).
inversion Heq.
Show Proof.
Defined.
```

I have to prove something like that:

```
Theorem update_vector_correctly : forall {A} n y (x : vector A (S n)) (H : S n >= S y) v, get_value (set_value x (S y) v) (S y) = Some v.
```

So I got three cases.

```
when (for y and n),
     S y <= S n.
     0 <= S n.
     0 <= 0.
```

However if you notice the case 3, for example is an absurd, once `0 <> S n`, for all `n`, so I have to remember that `(S n)` is a succ number.

When I use this : 
 remember (S n).

I get :

```
H : 0 <= 0
Heqn0 : 0 = S n
```

But in the first case I get :

```
H0 : n1 = S n -> get_value (set_value v0 y0 v) y0 = Some v
Heqn0 : S n1 = S n
```

which is neither a false case or true case.
The problem is that my hypothesis is `n`, but I have to return a `P (S n) _ _ (next _ _)`, therefore an equality relation doesn't walk "together" the induction, in the end remember always get a weird problem.

Comment: What is your definition of `vector` here? I would rather see the definitions than the proof of `vector_ind_with_leb` which seems irrelevant. I assume you're using it to try and prove your theorem. If you could simplify your example so that I can run it, I would be grateful. :)

Comment: Oh, thank you. The definition of the vector is the same of coq library vectordef. `Inductive vector (A : Type) : nat -> Type :=
  |insert : forall (n : nat), A -> vector A n -> vector A (S n)
  |empty : vector A 0`. The problem is to prove the update_vector_correctly theorem i need a leb value because the following cases is a absurd for  update_vector_correctly, if vector is empty or if index is bigger than vector length.

Comment: I'd suggest you edit your original question with the definition of `vector`, `get_value` and `set_value`, and remove the proof of `vector_ind_with_leb`, leaving only the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to `generalize dependent n` between the `remember` and the `induction`.  The problem that you are running into is as follows:

You have that `n1 = S n` for a given `n`, and you want to induct over `n1` (actually over the vector, but that doesn't matter for our purposes).  Coq first generalizes your goal over everything that depends on `n1` (including the proof that `n1 = S n`).  But this is the wrong induction hypothesis; you are not trying to prove your statement by induction only when `n1` is the successor of this particular `n`.  Instead you want to prove your statement when `n1` is the successor of *any* `n`, and hence you must generalize over `n` before performing induction.

As an alternative, in this case, you could first prove that `S n <> 0`, and then you don't need to `remember` anything, as your third case will already have an absurd hypothesis.

Comment: I solve this problem specializing in the induction scheme for

(P : forall n y: nat, y < S n -> vector A (S n) -> Prop),
, so Coq don't try to generalize the S n, for any m natural. I even tried to prove that S n <> 0, but it just messed up my hypothesis (i don't know if used this correctly).

Anyway, I am really grateful for your answer I will consider this as an acceptable answer.

Thanks.